# How to perform type casting to undefined or null?

Tags: typescript

I want to force an object out of scope like,

```
let obj: typeA = aTypeAobj;

function del(obj: typeA): void {
  obj = undefined;
}
```

But Typescript under `strict` mode does not allow me to do so.

I could do like,

```
let obj: typeA = aTypeAobj;

function del(obj: typeA | undefined): void {
  obj = undefined;
}
```

But in that case I can also pass any `undefined` type also.

Is there any way to type-cast inside the function body like,

```
let obj: typeA = aTypeAobj;

function del(obj: typeA): void {
  obj<typeA | undefined> = undefined; // this doesn't work but I'm asking something like this
}
```

Then I could get the advantage of ts blocking any `undefined` type as parameter to `del()` as well as assigning the `typeA` object to `undefined`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to allow setting variables to `undefined` even if they are not declared as allowing it, you can cast them to `any`. For instance:

```
(<any>obj) = undefined
```

The parentheses are necessary. Or what I usually use:

```
(obj as any) = undefined;
```

If you want to be more restrictive, you can use:

```
(obj as (undefined | typeA)) = undefined;
```

or:

```
(<undefined|typeA>obj) = undefined;
```